# Replace multiple Spaces to single space with - in angular js data binding

Tags: angularjs

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.removeSpace=function(){
  $scope.name = $scope.name.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input name="txtName" type="text" ng-focus="true" ng-model="name"
 ng-change="removeSpace()" autocomplete="off" list="name"
 class="form-control" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="50"
 ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z- ]*$/" placeholder="Name" required>
 </div>
```

**.html code**

```
 < input name="txtName" type="text" ng-focus="true" ng-model="name"
 ng-change="removeSpace()" autocomplete="off" list="name"
 class="form-control" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="50"
 ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z- ]*$/" placeholder="Name" required >
```

**.js file code**

$scope.removeSpace=function(){
 
            $scope.name =
     $scope.name.replace(/\s+/g, ' '); 
 }

```
 O/p:- name :- atul              n          kumar

Error: $scope.name is undefined
```

below o/p when i enter this name on textbox but change event is not properly worlk. i enter twenty or more spaces between name then after give error. I want to "**atul n kumar**" output. then not replace multi space to single space.

Comment: Can you post a pastebin/jsfiddle, that error doesn't appear to be related to the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace spaces only and not tabs or newlines you can do so;

```
$scope.nam = $scope.nam.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing a problem in your code.

You can see this jsBin in which you can see it works properly

https://jsbin.com/zexomineti/edit?html,js,output

However, notice I wrapped removeSpace with a check that name exists, because the ng-change can be called when name is still undefined, which caused the error you saw.

You cannot call replace on name if name is still undefined.

So:

```
$scope.name.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

Is:

```
if ($scope.name){
  $scope.name = $scope.name.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
}
```

Comment: thankz rotem, your suggesion code is work upto 20 spaces  then after it doesn't check condition because of undefined but I want solution to replace all spaces in to single space.

Comment: This is due to ng-maxlength="50", when the spaces causes the string length to go above the valid length, so the value is undefined during the ng-change